# How android service will redeliver intents after calling stopself

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I'm trying to understand how the service will behave when onStartCommand will return START_REDELIVER_INTENT.

If we assume that from an activity we call the service several times. In onStartCommand we receive the intent and a startID. For example the following have been received:

`onStartCommand - intent A, startID = 1`

`onStartCommand - intent B, startID = 2`

`onStartCommand - intent C, startID = 3`

`onStartCommand - intent D, startID = 4`

`onStartCommand - intent E, startID = 5`

1) If I call the stopself(id=3) and the service is killed, will intents with startID 1, 2, 4 and 5 redelivered? or only the intents with id higher that the one given in the stopself are redelivered, i.e. 4 and 5?

2) If I call the stopself() does it mean that intents that have been scheduled for redelivery are cancelled?

Any feedback is appreciated,

Lupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few statements from Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelfResult%28int%29)

```
"Stop the service if the most recent time it was started was startId"
```

> "allows you to safely avoid stopping if there is a start request from
>   a client that you haven't yet seen in onStart(Intent, int)."

So in your example, calling stopSelf(3) will not stop your service. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks for the response, I'm interested about the redelivery of intents, could you provide some feedback on my questions indicating what intents will be redelivered at each case?

Comment: your service will NOT be killed with stopSelf(3) like said above. But yes service might get killed by framework because of low memory conditions. Say, service was killed after returning from onStartCommand(intent, 4). When there is enough memory, platform will restart your service and then deliver 4 and then 5.